# In Alt HConcat , is it possible to define strokeWidth individually for each (i.e. not use configure_* , which can only be applied to Top level)?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a need to have a left side faceted chart (using `mark_rect`) that has several small-multiples/mini charts. On the right, I would like to label them by their title using `mark_text`.
The concatenation works fine using  `(left | right)` , however I have a need to remove the box that is on the view from `mark_text`

Example code describing my is below:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[['BookA',0,'Hello',3],
['BookA',0,'World',1],
['BookA',1,'Hello',1],
['BookA',1,'World',0],
['BookA',2,'Hello',4],
['BookA',2,'World',2],
['BookB',0,'Hello',0],
['BookB',0,'World',0],
['BookB',1,'Hello',2],
['BookB',1,'World',3],
['BookC',0,'Hello',1],
['BookC',0,'World',0],
['BookC',1,'Hello',1],
['BookC',1,'World',2],
['BookC',2,'Hello',3],
['BookC',2,'World',4],
['BookC',3,'Hello',0],
['BookC',3,'World',0],
], columns = ['title','line','var','val']
)

base = alt.Chart(df)

#    Left chart containing heatmap
left = base.mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('line:O',axis=alt.Axis(tickSize=0,labels=False,title="",domain=False)),
    y=alt.Y('var:O',axis=alt.Axis(tickSize=0,title="",labelFontSize = 12,labelPadding = 6,domain=False)),
    color= alt.Color('val:O',scale=alt.Scale(scheme="blues"),legend=None),
    facet=alt.Facet('title:N', columns=1,header=alt.Header(labelExpr="''",labelOrient="right",title=""))
    ).resolve_scale(
    x='independent' #Make each plot have scale of x-axis only as per desired length
    ).properties(height = 50)
    
#    Right chart containing Book title
right = base.mark_text(strokeOpacity = 1, 
                                                dx= 300, #Added to shift by right
                                                fontSize = 14,fontWeight = 'normal', baseline='top').encode(
    text = alt.Text('title'),
    facet=alt.Facet('title:N', columns=1,header=alt.Header(labelExpr="''",labelOrient="right",title=""))
    ).properties(height = 51)

(left | right).configure_view(stroke='black',strokeWidth=2)
```

I would ideally like to remove the black bordered boxes that appear in the middle. If I set `strokeWidth = 0` in `configure_view`, it affects the `left` visualization in the below image, which I do not wish to.[image: Black border issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually edit the properties of the chart object instead of using the `configure_view` method. This means you can add it to the `view` property of the chart dictionary instead of using `config.view` (not sure if this could have side effects):

```py
left.view = {}
left.view['stroke'] = 'black'
left.view['strokeWidth'] = 3
(left | right).configure_view(stroke=None)
```

[image]

Also note that if you use `alt.hconcat` there is a `padding` parameter that can achieve what you are doing with `dx` now, note sure if there is an advantage practically in your case, but its purpose is to separate concatenated plots so might be useful to know of in general.

Comment: Thanks @joelostblom. This was exactly what I was looking for. It was hard to find documentation around accessing the `view` property and this information definitely helps a lot !